# Check if NSString contains a common first name on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, nsstring

I am wondering what the best approach would be to check whether or not a common first name is contained within an NSString on an iPhone app. I've got a sorted flat text file of ~5500 common American first names delimited by new lines. The NSString I am searching within for a name is not very long, most likely the size of a normal sentence.

My original plan was to load the sorted list into memory and then iterate over every word in the NSString performing a binary search of the list to determine whether or not that word was a common name.

Am I better off trying to put this name list into CoreData or a SQLite table and performing a query with that? My understanding is I would not have to load the entire list into memory if I went that route.

I am guessing this situation is a common problem with word dictionaries for word games, so I'm just wondering what the best practice is for fast lookups. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `check whether or not a common first name is contained within an NSString`.  Does this mean `A user named John entered.`, or does it mean `John`?  In other words, does the string you are checking consist of nothing but the name, or must the name be found in a string that contains "other stuff" besides the name?  This can make a difference in the approach chosen.  Also, "how quickly" do you need this to be done?

Comment: The name must be found in a string that contains "other stuff" besides the name. The string is not long, a standard sentence maybe 50 - 100 characters. Would like it as quick as possible, but I realize there is the trade-off with memory.

Comment: Well, if speed was a concern, I'd probably build a DFA of the ~5500 names on the fly.  You could serialize the DFA to non-volatile storage if you needed to. The DFA would have to be Unicode aware, probably go with UTF8 for convenience. Then I'd probably use `CFStringGetCStringPtr` / `CFStringGetBytes` to grab a UTF8 copy of the string, and run the DFA on it.  The performance would be ~ `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the string to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite sounds ideal for this in terms of both speed of lookup and minimising memory usage. It would also make it potentially possible to update the first name list over the internet if so desired.

Using Core Data (which is in effect an elabourate wrapper around SQLite) would be overkill in this instance, especially as you don't require the ORM like capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

An NSSet might be useful as well. [Dave DeLong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703936/nsdictionary-nsarray-nsset-and-efficiency/2705313#2705313) for another question demonstrates that NSSets have constant look-up times, i.e. O(1).

Load your names into an NSMutableSet one by one. This will be the slowest part but will only need to be done once. If your file is a simple line-delimited file of names, it may be easier to use the standard C library for reading the file, since line-by-line input is not well-supported by Cocoa.

After that, simply use `[nameSet containsObject:name]` to check whether it is in the list.

A couple of drawbacks to this approach:

1. The name you want to test must be in the same case as the name in the set, that is “paul” and “Paul” are different strings. You can circumvent this by converting all names to lowercase before inserting them into the set, and then also converting the name you want to check into lowercase before checking it against the set.
2. It might be easier just to go with the already-accepted answer.

Comment: This approach seems more straightforward to me, but I think I'm going with SQLite just so I don't need to load everything into memory upfront -- although it may not really be an issue with only 5500 entries.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, why on earth use a framework-supplied data structure dedicated for speedy lookups when you can enjoy the overhead of an SQL parser for nothing other than looking something up in a 1-column table. </sarcasm>