# Question mark as "if" notation

Tags: objective-c

I'm aware of using syntax like this:

```
(something) ? TRUE : FALSE
```

But what if i want to return checking variable? For example:

```
if([myVar objectForKey:objectName])
    return [myVar objectForKey:objectName]
else
    return -1;
```

Is there a syntax like first line of code here that do that?

Of course i know that i can simply do something ***like***:

```
([myVar objectForKey:objectName]) ? return [myVar objectForKey:objectName] :  return -1;
```

But this is AFAIK very ugly solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I *think* this should work *(EDIT: but see andyvn22's answer re: return types)*:

```
id foo;
return (foo = [myVar objectForKey:objectName]) ? foo : -1;
```

As a general rule, though, you're almost always better off using an easy to understand notation than one that is slightly more concise but cryptic.

Comment: That syntax is EXACTLY what am i looking for. But I have to declared it outside my *if* statement? I can't declare it in *if*?

Comment: Can't remember what the scoping rules would mean for such a declaration, but I don't think it'll work. You could try it and see?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but you could always do something like:

```
id foo = [myVar objectForKey:objectName];
return (foo) ? foo : -1;
```

or

```
return [myVar objectForKey:objectName] ? [myVar objectForKey:objectName] : -1;
```

Comment: Oooo return goes to start. Thanks, but I have my doubts about this. Maybe its trivial but it is better create an variable (like you did in first line of code) or maybe getting object from dictionary twice? I know that both works but whitch is better for the memory?

Comment: I don't think the effect on memory will be too different. In the first case, you're allocating a pointer on the stack. That's only 8 bytes. In the second case, you're calling the `objectForKey:` method twice. It's a performance difference, but probably not a big one unless it's inside an inner loop.

Comment: You're right that the latter example *might* call `-objectForKey:` twice, but any differences would be so small it's *absurd* to care about them--use whichever format is *most readable* to you. If we were instead discussing `return [myVar ridiculouslySlowMethod] ? [myVar ridiculouslySlowMethod] : -1`, *then* you might want to us the first version.

Comment: Thanks, but searching through big NSDictionary is not expensive operation? I'm always thinking that it is.

Comment: It's lookup time is O(1), according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703936/nsdictionary-nsarray-nsset-and-efficiency). Like anything, you should profile to see where the slowdowns will be in your specific code. It is a method call, so regardless of its running time, if it's in an inner loop (for example, being called per channel per pixel in a gigapixel image), it could slow things down. But whether that's likely for your code depends on what your code does.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* an easy way to use the ternary operator (that's what that `? :` syntax is called) in a `return` statement:

```
return [myVar objectForKey:objectName] ? [myVar objectForKey:objectName] : -1;
```

And it can be made more concise with a quick variable:

```
id result = [myVar objectForKey:objectName];
return result ? result : -1;
```

However! What's your return type here? There's a possibility you'll return `[myVar objectForKey:objectName]`, which is of type `id`, or that you'll return `-1`, which is of type `NSInteger`. One's an Objective-C object and the other is a C primitive--something seems fishy with this specific example.

Comment: Thanks for the name! Now I know what i'm looking for. I know about the types, It's more a general question than issue with return type.